# Sharepoint Online REST: Lists' Enable audience targeting setting

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

Is it possible to get and/or set the `List Settings > Audience targeting settings > Enable audience targeting` on or off with the Sharepoint REST API?

I've tried checking the `GET <web-url>/_api/Lists(guid'<list-id>')` response of the same list before and after toggling the setting, but the only things that changed was the `odata.etag`, the `CurrentChangeToken` and the `LastItemModifiedDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a property of the list class. If the "Enable audience targeting" is checked, the list will have a field with `Type="TargetTo" Name="Target_x0020_Audiences" DisplayName="Target Audiences" guid "61cbb965-1e04-4273-b658-eedaa662f48d"`.

You can check the fields for the list fields using API "`/_api/Lists(guid'<list-id>')/fields`". You will find this field only if the audience targeting is enable.

For example:

[image]

To enable/disable audience targeting for this list, you may need to add/remove this field to/from list using REST API.

[How to manage list using REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#working-with-lists-by-using-rest).

[Here is a demo](http://blog.softreeconsulting.com/sharepoint/enable-or-disable-audience-targeting-of-a-list-in-sharepoint/) about how to enable or disable Audience targeting of a list in SharePoint using CSOM (just for your reference):