SharePoint SE PowerShell Enable Audience Targeting on list
I'm trying to enable Audience Targeting on a list with PowerShell. I'm using SharePoint Subscription Edition.
I tried different scripts with Sharepoint module, pnp module, or API, but I was not able to find the property EnableAudienceTargeting or receive an error 401(Unauthorized) for Invoke-RestMehtod.
I can do it manually via list settings on the site.
Can you help me for this?
Thank you.
Philippe

Check these links: https://github.com/bkuppens/powershell/blob/master/Enable-AudienceTargetingOnList.ps1
and  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/257844/sharepoint-online-rest-lists-enable-audience-targeting-setting
